# Phonegap App : Get previous video current time on video change

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am developing a phonegap app where I have a video player.

When the user changes and switches to next video, I want to write the time duration of the video seen by the user.

My html tag for video is:

```
<video id="upVid" width="100%" height="350" controls="controls">
<source src="file:///sdcard/" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did for something similar. In the controller actually get the element and add an event listener to the timeupdate event of the video:

```
$scope.audio = document.getElementById("upVid");
$scope.audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e){ 
     $scope.currentTime = floatToTime(this.currentTime);
     $scope.$apply();
     return;
}
```

And then here is floatToTime function:

```
function floatToTime( ms ){
    var hr = (ms/3600) << 0,
    min = (ms/60) << 0,
    sec = (ms << 0) % 60;
    return (hr >= 1 && ( hr + ':' )) + min + ':' + sec;

}
```

Now you just need a place to display the current time:

```
<div>{{currentTime}}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer actually I want to get the current time of the last video played.

Comment: Sorry about that. Try this, please.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is really very helpful. Can I use some functions like whenever the user changes the video or exits from the player then the current time will be recorded.

Comment: Well, the `$scope.currentTime` is already recorded and will stay that way until the video element's current-time changes. If the user moves away from the video player, `$scope.currentTime` will still maintain its previous value.